# Python not reading entire file

Tags: python

This is a really simple question but I just can't figure out why its happening. Am trying to print an entire body of text but the following codes only print about half or less of it:

```
textfile = open("helloworld.txt")
body = textfile.read()
print body
```

and

```
textfile = open("helloworld.txt")
for line in textfile:
    line = line.rstrip()       
    print line
```

Comment: Those strategies should work. Without more information, we can't provide a solution.

Comment: Looks proper at first glance. The problem could be with the file, not the code

Comment: Can you post the file?

Comment: Do you mean copy the entire body of text here?

Comment: If the entire body of text is required to reproduce the problem, and it isn't gigantic, then yes. Otherwise, no. The idea is a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

the code submitted before me makes absolutely no sense above, why would you decode utf-8 to encode it again in utf-8?

Forget it, but let me give it a try.

Here's my suggestion `print open('FileLocation').read()`

**This could be more of an os problem than a python problem**. If the os doesn't like certain data, it may replace or not even print such character to a terminal/cmd

I personally use Linux, and never ran into such a problem. The problem could stem further down into memory usage aswell, but I somewhat doubt this since it doesn't throw you any errors. Could you possibly sample your document, so me or someone else may play with it to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

When faced with similar issues - I have usually found the problem to be due to bad UTF-8 Encoding. Python will crash out when it sees this bad data.

I therefore use 1 of two ways to overcome it

1) Convert before the python code i.e.

cat Some_File.txt | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c | python my_py_code.py

The -c switch means ignore bad UTF-8 characters.

2) Using python only

```
ifp=open('Some_File.txt','r')
all_text=''
for line in ifp:
    all_text=all_text+line.decode('utf-8','errors'='Ignore').encode('utf-8')
print(''+all_text)
ifp.close()
```

Hope that helps